# Downgrade iOS 10 beta 2 to iOS 10 beta 1?

Tags: ios, downgrade

I'm just curious. I know you can downgrade to iOS 9.3.2 from iOS 10, but I'm wondering if it's possible to downgrade between beta versions.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have a physical copy of that previous beta then you should be able to do it thru DFU mode but it's Not Recommended to downgrade and bear in mind that these betas do expire after a certain date and the earlier the number the sooner they'll expire.

Comment: What do you mean by physical copy?

Comment: @ghostpotato he means an ipsw file.

Comment: Sorry for my late response, but I meant the actual **ipsw** file

Comment: I don't actually have the IPSW file; I installed the first beta OTA. Where can I download the IPSW file?

Comment: Under normal circumstances Apple doesn't provide those download links of a previous beta release so unfortunately I can't really help you further.